# Opening a side menu on click on a TAB bar in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to make something like below snapshots.

When I click on profile tab bar instead of opening a new view controller it shows a side menu. Is it something that has been handled on click of tabbar ?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Could you do what you wanted? @Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to achieve something like your screenShot then you are using a wrong library, because when you show your right `viewController` the front `viewController` go to left by amount of width of your right `viewController`, but anyways here is the code for what you need to do

first you need to put your viewController as delegate of your TabBarViewController and in `func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool` you need to return false and call the method of SWRevealViewController to show right viewController `rightRevealToggleAnimated(true)`

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var sliderControl: UISlider!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.revealViewController().delegate = self
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        //self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    //checking for specific viewController
    if(viewController is DesiredViewControllerClass) {
        self.revealViewController().rightRevealToggleAnimated(true)
    }
    return false
}


}
```

I hope this helps you, regards

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what I want to achieve is that when I click on "PROFILE" button, instead of going on profileviewcontroller it should show this menu. It is like profile tab will just act as a button which calls the menu out but the focus on first view controller will not shift.

Comment: you need to show right menu instead of button action? is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the profile tab to be there but the right menu should come on its click and no change should be made on TabViewController.
 Suppose I am currently on first tab that is Listing and I click on the fifth tab (profile). So, in normal cases the focus will shift to profile tab but in my case I want the right menu to come and the focus should remain on the first tab.

Comment: You are using a UITabBarViewController or just a TabBar?

Comment: I am using a UITabBarController and then adding various view controller to it.

Comment: my answer was edited @Sam you need to implement this method `func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool` instead, this will keep in currentViewController and show the right menu, regards. I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks a ton! you are awesome :)

Comment: Thanks, everything is working fine but when I call reveal view controller in this call self.revealViewController().rightRevealToggleAnimated(true); it shifts my screen by the amount of width od reveal view controller. Is there any solution to this ?

Comment: how would you set up the storyboard for this? @Reinier Melian

Comment: @ReinierMelian But, how to know which tab we are showing the menu for me it is showing menu when I click any of the tabs..

Comment: you can check viewController class type, and react accordingly hope this helps you @VenkateshChejarla

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thanks for the immediate response.. I tried `if viewController == menuNavigationController() { self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true) }`, but nothings happens. I would be so thankful, if you could update the code or you could just comment.. Thanks.

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla you need to check for type, dont for object, I mean if your menuNavigationController class is `MenuNavigationController` you need to check `if(viewController is MenuNavigationController) { //your code here}` check my answer was updated anyway

Comment: Glad to help you @VenkateshChejarla happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tab bar delegate:

```
extension ViewController: UITabBarDelegate {
    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        // Present hamburger menu
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but can you please elaborate. This view controller class will be the class of the 5 View controller ?

Comment: but how to add button without a ViewController in tabbar ....